# Android Manifest file messed up after rebuild

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a bit new at this, so please forgive me:

In Android Studio, I went to the Build menu and rebuilt my project (mostly out of curiosity, since I'm still new and want to learn what everything does). However, this had the unintended side effect of completely screwing over my Android Manifest file, which is shown:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.jeffv.shakesperianinsultkit">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.jeffv.shakesperianinsultkit.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Android Studio is giving me 'unable to resolve' errors on `@string/app_name`, `MainActivity`, `@style/AppTheme`, and `@drawable/ic_launcher`.

So, I ask you all: What did I screw up, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Clean your project again

Comment: That means your String file is corrupted, go to res -> values and check string and styles xml files for the following `@style/apptheme` etc..